# How declare type of dict containing classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I'm tring to declare type of following function parameter with `typing` module:

```
import typing


class A(object):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass

def my_func(p: typing.Dict[A, str]) -> None:
    pass

my_func({C: 'foo'})
```

`p` parameter of `my_func` must be `dict` with childclass of `A` as key and `str` as value. Actual notation fail with `mypy` check:

> example.py:17: error: List item 0 has incompatible type "Tuple[C, str]"

How to declare type of `p` with typing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is using the class `C` itself as a key, not an instance of the `C`.

```
my_func({C: 'foo'})
```

Passing the instance of C class should be fine.

```
my_func({C(): 'foo'})
         ^^^--- instance, not a class itself
```

---

If you really need to pass the class itself (I doubt it), you need to use [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type):

```
typing.Dict[typing.Type[A], str]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```